# $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-1^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-2^2}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-n^2}})=\frac{\pi}{6}$, but how?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let
>  $s_n=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-r^2}}$ 
>  which of the following is  $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n $ ? 
> a) $\pi/2$ 
> b) $\pi/6$ 
> c) $1/2$ 
> d) $\infty$

**My approach** 
we have that, for every $r$ such that $1\leq r \leq n; r^2\leq n^2 \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-n^2}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-r^2}} \implies s_n \leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{4n^2-n^2}}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{3n^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3} $
 Hence $s_n$ is a bounded sequence of positive real numbers, where $s_n$ is the partial sum of the series $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-r^2}}$ confirming monotonicity. Therefore, $s_n$ is a convergent sequence.

> **Hence, we discard option (d)**

Now, $\pi\approx 3.14 >3 \implies \frac{\pi}{2}>\frac{3}{2}=1.5>1>\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ which contradicts the fact that $s_n<\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$

> **Hence, we discard option (a)**

Now,$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-1^2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-r^2}}\ \forall \ 1 \leq r\leq n $ 
So, $\frac{n}{\sqrt{4n^2-1^2}}< s_n\ as\ \forall\ r>1; \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-1^2}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-r^2}}$
Hence, $\frac{1}{2}< \lim_{n\to \infty}s_n$

> **Hence, we discard option (c)**

> **As, we are left with option (b) only, I conclude that it is the correct option.
> But how to prove it ?**

Answer (score 3):

We want to find
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-r^2}}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^2}}.
$$
This last limit is just a Riemann sum for the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 - x^2}} d x
$$
which is indeed $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful